# How to navigate from within one micro frontend to another

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend

My team and have started to code a new platform for the company we're working for and we chose to use micro frontends with ReactJS, which is something we never messed with before.

We chose to use NX as a boilerplate so we can create the project easily and more intuitive.

One thing that we don't understand and couldn't find out yet is how can we navigate from within one micro frontend to another.

For example:

We have an authentication micro frontend project which responsible for the sign in / sign up operations, and once the user finish the process he should be navigated to another micro FE which is the dashboard.

We couldn't find out yet how to do it, so currently we're using the current code to manipulate the entire window's location.

`window.location.replace(`${config().baseUrl}${AppRoutes.Dashboard}`);`

Is there any way we can use anything like history.push (from react-router-dom) or anything equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your sample code?

Comment: @HaiTien sample code of what? as I said, when I want to navigate from one remote MFE to another remote MFE or to the shell application I use window.location, this is the sample.